# Submit a mainframe job using FitNesse, C# & FTPClient=JES

Tags: c#, ftp, mainframe, fitnesse, jes

Looking for a way to submit mainframe job using Framework FitNesse, C# & FTPClient "filetype=jes"

Tried with framework FitNesse, JAVA & FTPClient "filetype=jes", its working fine.

Comment: Sounds like FitNesse is not working...what is the failure?

Comment: Please post more information.  What does your working Java code look like?  What does your non-working C# code look like?  What error did you get?

Comment: We need detail, like logs.